# Search for a document whose permissions are broken in a site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, item-level-permissions

**Scenario:**  i am having a user called UserA, he uploads a document into a site assets library n my site collection, and went to the permissions for the document and removed all the permissions except his.

After this , i  performed the full crawl for this web application from search service application -content sources.
 After performing successfull full crawl, i logged into the site as another user called **userB** and performed the serach! this userB has **Full Read** access to the site collection.
Surprisingly userB is able to see the document with download capabilities.

**Question** : why this is happening ? As per SharePoint design and search func. a user who doesnt have the permission to the document should not see the document in search , though he has  full read access to the site collection.
So, here why the full read permission on the site collection overrides the itemlevel permissions on the item in the site assets library.
is this true? is this sharepoint default behaviour?

Comment: Is the FullRead permission to userB granted as a policy on the Web Application? If yes then user has read access to all content regardless of permissions.

Comment: you seem to be somewhat correct,@LarsFastrup . i have added **everyone** in the userpolicy of web appln in Central Admin .As per your suggestion, am removing everyone from fullread . Will this step resolve my issue ?

Comment: Yes it will resolve it! But you'll need a new full crawl to update the ACLs in the search index.

Comment: But do not remove the search crawler account! It will need full read to all content in order to index it.